# PHP DateTime and Interval unexpected behavior

Tags: php, loops, date, datetime, foreach

here is my code (using laravel)

```
$start = '05-01-2016';
$end = '05-03-2016';
$start_date = new Carbon;
$end_date = new Carbon;
$format = 'm-d-Y';
$begin = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $start);
$begin->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$end = Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $end);
$end->setTime(59, 59, 59);
//dd($begin,$end);
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
$dateRange = new \DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);
foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
    $start_time = $start_date->setDateTime($date->format("Y"), $date->format("m"), $date->format("d"), 0, 0, 0)->toDateTimeString();
    $end_time =$end_date->setDateTime($date->format("Y"), $date->format("m"), $date->format("d"), 23, 59, 59)->toDateTimeString();
    var_dump($start_time);
    //var_dump($end_time);
}
```

expected output would be (atleast for me)

```
05-01-2016
05-02-2016
```

it actually gives me

```
05-01-2016
05-02-2016
05-03-2016
05-04-2016
05-05-2016
```

I cant understand it... any help is appreciated

here is output
[image]

Comment: is that a bug? otherwise,someone would have replied me till now

Comment: whoever down-voted it, deserves a solute, because I deserve this..I took an hour and finally the help by the fantastic guy below to figure that out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set 59 hour :) - It is more than two days. Now your end datetime is `Thu, 05 May 2016 11:59:59`

```
$end->setTime(59, 59, 59);
```

Set 23 hours and it will work

```
$end->setTime(23, 59, 59);
```

Comment: damn damn damn me.....I wouldn't believe that's me... thanks bro... I was hitting my head on wall over this....

Comment: Such mistakes are really hard to find. The required a fresh look :)

Comment: you are really right bro...it took atleast an hour...I even started wonder that may be its a bug...but the bug was in my eyes and code...not in DateTime or interval :( anyway, I really owe for this

Comment: Glad that could help. Good luck!